# What actions earn Imperial Bux?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Imperial Bux are used to speed up many processes throughout the game. You can get more through microtransactions and completing various affiliate actions outside the game.

[image]

What in game actions allow you to earn Imperial Bux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Starting to build a new level.
2. Hiring a bitizen to work in their dream job shop.
3. Performing any of the "Find a Bitizen" flavor missions.
4. On a bitizen's birthday, you will earn a bux.

Answer (score 5):

A few other ways to earn bux:

Ferrying people to their floors will occasionally result in a tip in the form of 1 Bux.  It's rare but it happens.

Fully stocking a floor will rarely earn you 1 Bux.

You will receive 1 Bux on the birthday of any of your bitizens.

If you fail to capture a rebel spy who is also a ? citizen, you will earn 2 bux.  IF you do capture them, you get 1 bux.

[image: Stocking bonus 1 bux.]

Comment: I've never seen the tip of a bux in Tiny Death Star, nor have I seen fully stocking a floor to earn a bux. In just a couple of hours of play on Tiny Tower, I've seen the tipping of a bux, so I don't think this is implemented in Tindy Death Star.

Comment: I've never played Tiny Tower. So, its unlikely I've confused the two.  These are all situations I've encountered in game. You'll note the rarity that I mentioned.  Like many things in this game, I think they become rarer as play progresses.

Comment: Or they have been removed to make Tiny Death Star more distinct from Tiny Tower. In Tiny Tower, bux "rain down" on the player in comparison to Tiny Death Star. But it effectively has "unlimited" amount of floors in that players can customize an individual shop or residence. There is no customizing in TDS, so the designers may have cut back on the bux reward rate to help extend the game content play time.

Comment: My death star has like 50 levels, and I think I've gotten bux for fully stocking two times.  So it does happen, but it's exceedingly rare in TDS, at least on my device

Comment: See picture above . . .

Comment: @DavidM What platform do you play TDS on? iOS? Android?

Comment: @glibdud - I play on iOS

Comment: Maybe there's a platform difference. I'm on Android and have put an embarrassing amount of hours into the game in the last week, but I've yet to see any Bux as a tip or full stock bonus. If they're _that_ rare, then I'm not sure I see the point in having the feature at all.

Comment: It's random, and rare.  Just a treat for prolonged play.  But, it does happen (see pic above . . .).

Comment: I got bux for fully stocking at least 5-10 times (with 64 levels). For me it's hard to see because I've learned to tap those messages away immediately.
Moreover, at this point I sometimes get 2 bux for capturing rebels, and only 1 when they escape. I don't know whether that's because of a game update, or because of progressing in the game.

Answer (score 3):

I got crazy bux when playing without buying any. level 5 elevator upgrade before level 40 was built. It took a little work though, planning, and a little bit or strategy in how you approach the game.

How I did it:
Short version, you have more open residential space than you have for jobs. When you have a bitzen move in you evict him immediately unless you have his dream job. When one moves in that has a dream job, you fill it and get a bux. The secret is you keep the bitizens getting dream jobs by having a revolving door on your death star. Get a new bitizen, unemploy one of your bitizens that have the job, employ the new one with their dream job, and collect their bux. Then you evict them and put your original guy back in. Every time you do this is a free bux!

Long version on how I got it to work for me:

1. I slowly built the first levels out in a sales>homes>sales>homes fashion.
2. I took a lot of time kicking off bitizens until my first few levels were full of dream jobs. I did place one or two in there to stock so I would have some cash flow. this is where your patients comes in. this will probably take more time than just shoving people were ever.
3. **I kept every housing level with 1 or 2 openings**. That way I always had steady flow of bitizens moving in.
4. I evicted all who I didn't have the level to match their dream job.
5. Once I had all three openings filled with dream jobs, I still kept moving in new bitizens and replacing them or swapping the new in for just long enough to get the bux, then swapped them back out to the old bitizen.
6. Collect Bux for every swap made.
7. Ride the gravy train!

Example 1 (early game):

Level 2 — Apt with two open spots for new Bitizens
Level 3 — Mos Espa Cafe with one dream job and one not dream job
Level 4 — Apt with four open spots
Level 5 — Workout Center with one non dream job

I would boot fill one more in the workout center to keep money coming in. And when I got a new bitizen that didn't have those levels as a dream job, I immediately evicted them to keep the space open.

Example 2 (later game):

Level 2 — Apt with 2 open spots for new Bitizens
Level 3 — Mos Espa Cafe with 3 dream jobs (All skill 9)
Level 4 — Apt with 2 open spots
Level 5 — Workout Center with 3 dream jobs (Skill 4, 8, 9)
Level 6 — "Retail"
Level 7 — "Apt" with at least one open spot.
etc.

I would still boot all that I couldn't put into a dream job immediately as they moved in. When I got a new bitizen that had "Workout center" Skill 5. I would evict the one with skill 4 and place in the new one. (As you normally would). Next bitizen moves in and it has "Mos Espa Cafe" with a skill of 2. I would "unemploy" the skill 9, employ the skill 2. Get the bux. Evict skill 2 and re-employ the skill 9.

The bux come flowing in! Enjoy!

One other tip, I would highly recommend saving all your bux for the first 4 elevator upgrades. Level 5 cost 499 bux! Once I got to level 4, I started using a few bux here or there to finish things sooner, etc. but with keeping up the strategy of always having open housing for new bitizens to move in the bux still came flowing in! I had enough to get level 5 before I had 40 levels, Had I not spent any before 30 levels!

Comment: This is not really the answer to the question "Which actions earn Imperial Bux?"  It answers the question, Which strategies will earn me the MOST bux?

Comment: It would definitely. I just wanted to share though.

Answer (score 1):

The main way to earn bux is to do the "find the bitizen/Rebel Spy" missions, or to put bitizens in dream jobs.

Of course, they don't have to **keep** their dream job very long.  Just take one person already in the job, assign them to the job "unemployed" (obviously you will have to wait for the floor to finish any outstanding orders), hire the new person in their place, earn the bux, then evict them, and put the old person back.

This is obviously easier once your tower gets taller, as you'll have more floors, so a higher chance of having the floor to match the bitizen.

So the trick to getting that to work is to keep vacancies open on as many residential floors as you can, to improve the odds of the elevator taking a bitizen to a floor they can move into.  Vacancies = turnover = buxs.

Comment: If you take someone out of their dream job and put them back in, I assume that it does not re-reward you?

Comment: No; you can't sit there all day and swap two dream jobbers in and out to earn infinite buxs.